# Simplify/fix the following code

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

error "Cucumber cannot be resolved to a type" for the below code. Could someone suggest the solution.

```
      package runner;
      import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
      @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
      public class Testrunner {

       }
```

Comment: pls provide more details. like maven/gradle script. Have your included the jar file in your classpath

Comment: sorry.i did not get you...i imported all jar files

Comment: Looks like you don't have the import for `Cucumber` class.

Comment: i tried this import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

Answer (score 0):

For

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
```

you need **cucumber-junit** & **cucumber-java** version at least 1.2.0  in your classpath.

Comment: @chakradhar What version of cucumber-junit & cucumber-java do you have?

Comment: \jar_files\cucumber-html-0.2.6.jar
\jar_files\cucumber-java-2.3.1.jar
\jar_files\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.6.jar
\jar_files\gherkin-5.0.0.jar
\jar_files\tag-expressions-1.1.1.jar
\cucumber-core-2.3.1-sources.jar
\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar

Comment: @chakradhar You don't have cucumber-junit, that's why you get the error

Comment: @ Eugen Covaci Thanks a lotttt bro

Comment: @chakradhar You can accept the answer if it worked for you.